# Load DIV from another page into bootstrap modal, based on button Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a DIV from another page, based on the data attribute of the button clicked. Here is what I have so far:

```
$('#quick_shop_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event)
{
         var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
         var product = button.data('product')
         var modal = $(this)
         modal.find('.modal-title').text('Quick Shop ' + product)
         $('#quick_modal_body').load('product #prodDescMain')
});
```

So when the modal is opened, it should use the product data attribute of the button to load the #prodDescMain div of that page.

Data attribute example: Leather_Care_Kit.php

which means the last line should read:
`$('#quick_modal_body').load('Leather_Care_Kit.php #prodDescMain')`

However nothing shows up. If I hard code the filename it works though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`product` is a variable, so you use string concatenation:

```
$('#quick_modal_body').load(product + ' #prodDescMain')
```

Comment: Hmm, i have implemented your solution but it seems something else is wrong

Comment: Something else is definitely wrong, if I try to console.log(product) I get nothing either!